# Создать патч из not-staged файлов

Tags: git

Добрый день! У меня такой вопрос. Как в git сделать patch из non-staged файлов?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я использовал "`git diff >f.patch`", но периодически имел проблемы.
Применяется посредством "`git apply f.patch`". Git am такие патчи не распознаёт. Видите ли не хватает комментария к коммиту в виде subject'a :(